# Convert OLE Color to System.Drawing.Color in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, colors, compact-framework, type-conversion

I receive an OLE color from a 3rd party system and I need to convert this to a `System.Drawing.Color`.

On the full .Net Framework I can use `ColorTranslator.FromOle(int oleColor)`

to perform this conversion however this doesn't exist in the Compact framework. Any idea how to perform this conversion?

Thanks

---

Below is the answer.

```
int oleColor = 16711680;   // Blue
Color argbColor;

argbColor = Color.FromArgb((byte)(oleColor & 0xff), (byte)((oleColor >> 8) & 0xff), (byte)((oleColor >> 0x10) & 0xff));
```

Comment: Have a look: you can take 4 bytes from ole_color and use separate bytes to make color Color.FromArgb http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946077%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Cool. That got me on the right track.

Comment: What you have posted now is already good, don't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the tiral version of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and inspect the code of ColorTranslator.FromOle method.

Basically, There is a big switch case block where each case returns a Color structure with Color.FromKnownColor method.

[image: screenshot]